# With sf, selecting area features that contain at least one of a selection of point features?

Tags: r, r-sf

For example, let's say I have an `sf` object containing 4 cities in the contiguous United States and their coordinates. And then I have an `sf` object with 48 features (one for each possible state). Is there a way to select the subset of states that contain the designated cities? Something like:

```
cities_sf

state_sf %>%
  filter(states s.t. there exists x in cities_sf s.t. x in states_sf) +
  ggplot() +
  ...
```

**Edit**: `st_within(my_cities, my_states)` gave me

```
structure(list(290L, 378L, 51L, integer(0), 283L, 478L, 415L, 
380L, 489L, 64L, 189L, 184L, 311L, 488L, 66L, 73L, 49L, 1L, 
359L, 111L, 502L, 489L, 272L, 115L, 352L, 241L), predicate = "within", 
region.id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"24", "25", "26"), ncol = 544L, class = "sgbp")
```

I can tell that those 26 indices correspond to the multipolygons in `my_states` that contain the cities, but I'm not sure how to work with that SGBD ("sparse geometry binary predicate", according to the docs) object in `ggplot`/`geom_sf` terms

**edit 2**: I ended up using `slice(states_sf, unlist(st_within(cities_sf, states_sf)))`, which gives a `sf` object that is the subset I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

without sample data, this is the best I can come up with.

```
library( sf )

#find intersecting points/polygons    
intersect <- st_intersection(x = polygons, y = points)

#and go further from there
```

## update

Using the sample data @Spacedman provided in his answer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

states %>% 
  #create ID's for the states (if they don't have one already) 
  #state ID should be equal to rownumber (fot the filter later on)
  mutate( id = row_number() ) %>%
  #filter out states that do not have any intersetcions with the points/cities
  filter( id %in% unlist( st_intersects(cities, states) ) ) %>%
  #plot
  mapview::mapview()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how to provide sample data for this. The `geometry` sections of my `sf` objects are quite large. Do you have any suggestions? I did try your method (as best I could interpret it) and was not successful

Comment: It looks like `st_intersection` created an `sf` with type `POINT` instead of type `MULTIPOLYGON`. But I already know all the points are in the polygons, I'm interested in knowing which subset of polygons contains the points. I'm also looking at `st_covers` and `st_contains` after seeing your suggestion, but I'm having trouble understanding the documentation, which is a bit slim

Comment: `st_within` appears to be giving me the information I need, mostly? That seems most promising

Comment: @JohnDoeVsJoeSchmoe you can do a `dput(cities_sf)` and paste the output here in your question.

Comment: I'd prefer not to include my data, if that's alright? But I've made some progress such that I think I can ask a good question again: `st_within(cities_sf, states_sf)` met my needs, but I'm not sure how to work with what it produced. It gave me a "sparse geometry binary predicate" object that I've put in the main post. Do you know how to integrate that with the original multipolygon `states_sf` object?

Comment: Without actual sample data, the update in the answer is the best I can provide. Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually stumbled upon a similar solution using `slice(states_sf, unlist(st_within(cities_sf, states_sf)))` thanks to your initial comment in the meantime. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: I'm not sure why you are doing a `%in%` test on an intersection done in the order of `(cities, states)`. If you do an `intersects` of `(states, cities)` like in my answer you get a vector of the same length as the states which makes subsetting them much quicker. No need to generate row ids. If you really want to not use stable base R subsetting then `states %>% filter(lengths(st_intersects(states,cities) )> 0)` will do it with the current version of `dplyr`.

Comment: @Spacedman you are right. This was the first I came up with ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Using the us_states function from the `USAboundaries` packages, lets make a small set of states:

```
> states <- us_states(map_date = "2000-01-01", resolution = "high", states = c("CA", "OR", "WA","NV","NM","UT","CO","ID","AZ"))
```

and here's some points I created:

```
> pts
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 0 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -121.7663 ymin: 34.86508 xmax: -110.7263 ymax: 46.65593
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
                    geometry
1 POINT (-110.7263 34.86508)
2 POINT (-111.7345 38.64123)
3 POINT (-120.1531 46.65593)
4 POINT (-121.7663 39.37335)
```

To test for intersection:

```
> st_intersects(states, pts)
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes that they are planar
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 9, where the predicate was `intersects'
 1: 1
 2: 4
 3: (empty)
 4: (empty)
 5: (empty)
 6: (empty)
 7: (empty)
 8: 2
 9: 3
```

That object is a list, so you can get the length of the elements and find those that are bigger than zero - ie something is in there:

```
> lengths(st_intersects(states, pts)) > 0
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes that they are planar
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

and then subset your spatial polygons in the conventional way:

```
 > plot(st_geometry(states[lengths(st_intersects(states, pts)) > 0,]))
```

that plots the four states that have the four points in.

[image]

Create the subset and feed it to `ggplot` if that's how you are drawing the map.

Comment: As an alternative for this, you can use also the matrix obtained with the parameter `sparse = FALSE`, which compares every `x` geometries with every `y` geometries giving TRUE for any matching. For this case, `states %>% filter(apply(st_intersects(., pts, sparse = FALSE), 1, any))`.